# How to integrate non-Confluent connectors with Apache Kafka Connect

Tags: solr, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-kafka-connect

There is a requirement where we get a stream of data from Kafka Stream and our objective is to push this data to SOLR.

We did some reading but we could find there are lot of Kafka Connect solutions available in the market, but the problem is we do not know which is the best solution and how to achieve.

The options are:

1. Use Solr connector to connect with Kafka.
2. Use Apache Storm as it directly provides support for integrating with Solr.

There is no much documentation or in depth information provided for the above mentioned options.

Will anyone be kind enough to let me know

How we can use a Solr connector and integrate with Kafka stream without using Confluent?
**Solr-Kafka Connector**: https://github.com/MSurendra/kafka-connect-solr

Also, With regard to Apache Storm,
will it be possible for Apache Storm to accept the Kafka Stream and push it to Solr, though we would need some sanitization of data before pushing it to Solr?

Comment: What do you mean by "Confluent"? Things like Kafka Connect are generic to Apache Kafka, and not specific to Confluent Platform. Perhaps update your question to clarify exactly what and why you don't want to use it, so the answers can help you best.

Comment: Confluent doesn't have a Solr connector anyway, so I'm not sure how much help it would be if you did use it

Comment: Do you already have Storm? What difficulty are you having with a Kafka Spout and some other Solr Processor?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, please find the link to confluent. Even I am pretty new to Apache Kafka - https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Comment: @cricket_007, please find the link of solr sink connector :https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Comment: It is not **included**. I.e Confluent does not "have it", and you do not need Confluent to **use it**

Comment: By the way, Robin is a Confluent employee ;)

Comment: @cricket_007, Thanks for the info and the detailed steps. Do you by any chance know , if i am getting input as kafka streams in the form of some xml string, how can we intercept and push it to solr. Do we need to have a consumer which would intercept the stream and push it to connector class. Any help is appreciated. When i try to run the steps you had mentioned i get an error saying "sink task requires a list of topics." this i believe is because  i dont have any producer configured to create a stream or topic

Comment: Oops. sorry Robin :-(

Comment: Well, you need to edit your Connect property file to have a list of topics to send to Solr... And, no Kafka Connect is commonly used for CSV/plain strings, JSON, or Avro... You must write your own XML parser ahead of time... I would suggest using something like Apache Nifi rather than Kafka Connect because it offers some XPath processors as well as PutSolr. Brief intro https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/57262/integrating-apache-nifi-and-apache-kafka.html Otherwise, if Storm is what you have, then use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>I am avoiding Storm here, because the question is mostly about Kafka Connect</sup>

> **CAVEAT** - This Solr Connector in the question is using Kakfa 0.9.0.1 dependencies, therefore, it is very unlikely to work with the newest Kafka API's.
>
> **This connector is untested by me. Follow at your own risk**

The following is an excerpt from [Confluent's documentation on using community connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing.html#using-community-connectors), with some emphasis and adaptations. In other words, written for Kafka Connects not included in Confluent Platform.

---

### 1) Clone the GitHub repo for the connector

```
$ git clone https://github.com/MSurendra/kafka-connect-solr
```

### 2) Build the jar with maven

Change into the newly cloned repo, and checkout the version you want. ([This Solr connector has no releases like the Confluent ones](https://github.com/MSurendra/kafka-connect-solr/releases)).
You will typically want to checkout a released version.

```
$ cd kafka-connect-solr; mvn package
```

From here, see [Installing Plugins](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins)

### 3) Locate the connector’s uber JAR or plugin directory

We copy the resulting Maven output in the `target` directory into one of the directories on the Kafka Connect worker’s plugin path (the `plugin.path` property).
For example, if the plugin path includes the `/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins` directory, we can use one of the following techniques to make the connector available as a plugin.

[As mentioned in the Confluent docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins), the `export CLASSPATH=<some path>/kafka-connect-solr-1.0.jar` option would work, though `plugin.path` will be the way moving forward (Kafka 1.0+)

You should know which option to use based on the result of `mvn package`

#### Option 1) A single, uber JAR file

With this Solr Connector, we get a single file named `kafka-connect-solr-1.0.jar`.

We copy that file into the `/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins` directory:

```
$ cp target/kafka-connect-solr-1.0.jar /usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/
```

#### Option 2) A directory of dependencies

**(This does not apply to the Solr Connector)**

If the connector’s JARs are collected into a subdirectory of the build’s target directories, we can copy all of these JARs into a plugin directory within the `/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins`, for example

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/kafka-connect-solr
$ cp target/kafka-connect-solr-1.0.0/share/java/kafka-connect-solr/* /usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/kafka-connect-solr/
```

---

> #### Note
>
> Be sure to install the plugin on **all** of the machines where you’re running Kafka Connect distributed worker processes. It is important that *every connector* you use is available on all workers, since Kafka Connect will distribute the connector tasks to any of the worker

---

### 4) Running Kafka Connect

If you have properly set `plugin.path` or did `export CLASSPATH`, then you can use `connect-standalone` or `connect-distributed` with the appropriate config file for that Connect project.

---

Regarding,

> we would need some sanitization of data before pushing it to Solr

You would need to do that with a separate process like Kafka Streams, Storm, or other process prior to Kafka Connect. Write your transformed output to a secondary topic. Or write your own Kafka Connect Transform process. [Kafka Connect has very limited transformations](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) out of the box.

Also worth mentioning - [JSON seems to be the only supported Kafka message format for this Solr connector](https://github.com/MSurendra/kafka-connect-solr/tree/master/src/main/java/com/apache/kafka/connect/solr/converter)

Comment: Apologies in advance , if I am asking silly questions. For reading the input from an external kafka producer stream, Do i need to configure a source connector to listen and push to sink connector or does sink connector automatically listen to it.

Comment: Sink Connector will read from a comma separated list of pre-existing topics defined in the property file